# The SE logo lacks a transparent background when signing up for a new site with an SE account

Tags: bug, design

I just signed up for an account at [Christianity.SE](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/). The sign-up page looks like this:

[image]

The SE logo lacks a transparent bakground, so it kind of sticks out against the paper-pattern(?) used on the website.

Comment: Did you mean to post your email address for all to see?

Comment: @Oded Of course! How else are other unicorn-lovers supposed to get in touch with me?

Comment: Just making sure you didn't leak private information inadvertently ;)

Comment: It's because the logos come from [this CSS sprite sheet](http://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/openid/openid-logos.png), which indeed lacks transparency.

Comment: @Oded I think leakage questions better fit in http://parenting.stackexchange.com/ :D